# .Net Framework .resx portability to .Net Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

In .Net Core there are some changes to the APIs which resource generated resx/designer.cs files need.

Specifically `Type` no longer has the `Assembly` property directly on it... Core gets this through `Type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly`

The result is the designer.cs files are incompatible between frameworks, so a multi-targeted solution cannot use Resource files without compilation failing:

```
ConnectionDetails.Designer.cs(42,170): error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition 
for 'Assembly' and no extension method 'Assembly' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Visual studio knows how to generate these correctly depending on your project/solution type, but for multi-targeted solutions this isn't much help.

I haven't been able to find a workaround which works for both frameworks, since designer.cs is generated automatically.

Has anyone come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1519), caused by the fact that Visual Studio only uses the first item in the targeted-frameworks list for the purpose of Resx code generation. The workaround is to move a .Net Core or .Net Standard framework to the *first* position in the targeted-framework list, i.e.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.0;netstandard1.3;net45</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```